# Create a new vector formed by a list of vectors

Tags: r

Suppose I have m vectors: `a_1 = (a_{11}...a_{1n}) ... a_m = (a_{m1}...a_{mn})`
I want a new vector b of length mn such that
`b = (a_{11}...a_{m1} a_{12}...a_{m2}...a_{1n}...a_{mn})`
I can think of a for loop, for example:

```
>a<-c(1,1,1);b<-c(2,2,2);c<-c(3,3,3)
>x<-NULL
>for (i in 1:3) {x<-c(x,c(a[i],b[i],c[i]))}
>x
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or using `mapply`...

```
c( mapply( c , a , b , c )  )
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: Very nice except for the OP's use of `c` as an object name which results in a total readability fail. I would also suggest `as.vector` instead of `c` for coercing to a vector...

Answer (score 2):

```
c(matrix(c(a, b, c), nrow=length(a), byrow=TRUE))
```

Comment: Or `as.vector(rbind(a,b,c))`.